# Atomically exchange pointer with nullptr

Tags: c++, pointers, nullptr

How can I do the following operations in single atomic operation? Is that possible?

```
 LARGE_INTEGER* ptr; // field

 void method()
 {
       LARGE_INTEGER* local = ptr;
       ptr = nullptr;
 }
```

So I want to store pointer from field into local pointer and immediately set that field to `nullptr`.

In other words, I want to move pointer from field into local variable in single atomic operation.

Comment: `LARGE_INTEGER* local = InterlockedExchangePointer(&ptr, nullptr);` May need a cast on the first argument.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can it be lock free?

Comment: It is lock-free as shown.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it says `LARGE_INTEGER**` is incompatible with parameter of type `volatile PVOID *`

Comment: is this cast ok? (it compiles but not sure about runtime behavior) `LARGE_INTEGER* local = (LARGE_INTEGER*)InterlockedExchangePointer((PVOID*)&_ptr, nullptr);` if so you can post it as answer, I really appreciate that, thank you @IgorTandetnik

Comment: Use `std::atomic`, or re-implement the equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++11 you can use `std::atomic` for this purpose like this:

```
#include <atomic>
LARGE_INTEGER value;
std::atomic<LARGE_INTEGER*> ptr{&value};
LARGE_INTEGER* local = ptr.exchange(nullptr);
```